# How to Uniquely identify controls it the Coded UI in .Net C#

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, uniqueidentifier

We are helping out testers who write CodedUI tests for our project. The problem they have is that several dynamically added controls have no unique value to determine which is which.

My theoretical solution was to add a public custom property named "CodedUiName" to enable testers to map a control using this name. I've done this by sticking an ICodedUI interface on top a control and exposing above mentioned property.

I've checked this property using HawkEye Object Editor and it is actually there, but when testers do the same thing in CodedUI the property is not visible.

Is there a way for them to easily access the "CodedUiName".

We would like it to be a nice scale-able solution for any problematic controls we may encounter writing CodedUI tests.

Comment: Would you please present your code please?

Comment: can you add a logical name to each dynamically added control?

Comment: Isn't there an ID you have to add to every control? Something like `AutomationID`?

Comment: I am not sure how a CodedUI test works, but, to keep track of my dynamically created controls I used a `Dictionary<[key], Control>`. In my case the `[key]` is a `Form`. Then all of the `Control` references are in one "spot" for you to look at? (not sure if that helps) // Also, wouldn't it just be possible to use `Control.Equals(Control)` to tell them apart? Using their memory references as identifiers?

Comment: Set "AutomationProperties.AutomationIdProperty" for every control.